# Spread data into new columns, while also summarizing (adding) values - R or SQL

Tags: r, sql-server, dplyr

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID    YEAR    SOURCE    VALUE
 1    2014        AV       15
 1    2014        OV       25
 1    2015        AV       87
 2    2014        AX       44
 2    2015        AZ       32
 2    2015        NL        2
 3    2011        OV      104
```

I want to re-structure the table to provide a new column where the VALUEs provided from the sources AV, AX and NL are summed, and another new column where the values from OV are given.  For example, the above would look like this:

```
ID    YEAR    AV+AX+NL    OV
 1    2014          15    25
 1    2015          87    NA
 2    2014          44    NA
 2    2015          32    NA
 3    2011          NA   104
```

I would like to do this in R, but can use SQL if it's simpler.  So far I've been trying to combine the "summarise" and "mutate" commands from tidyverse to make my new columns, but I can't figure out a way to only sum certain SOURCE values rather than all of them.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);df1 %>%  group_by(ID, YEAR) %>% summarise(AV_AX_NL = sum(VALUE[SOURCE %in% c("AV", "AX", "NL")]), OV = sum(VALUE[SOURCE == "OV"]))`

Comment: what about the record where SOURCE == "AZ"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty Easy SQL Server Query. All you have to do is conditionally sum by criteria.

```
SELECT ID, [YEAR]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN SOURCE IN ('AV', 'AX', 'NL') THEN [VALUE] ELSE NULL END) [AV+AX+NL]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN SOURCE = 'OV' THEN [VALUE] ELSE NULL END) [OV]
FROM src
GROUP BY ID, [YEAR]
ORDER BY ID, [YEAR]
```

Results:

```
| ID | YEAR | AV+AX+NL | OV   |
+----+------+----------+------+
| 1  | 2014 | 15       | 25   |
| 1  | 2015 | 87       | NULL |
| 2  | 2014 | 44       | NULL |
| 2  | 2015 | 2        | NULL |
| 3  | 2011 | NULL     | 104  |
```

I originally used 0 as the alternative value when the condition in the case isn't matched.  However if you want NULL to be displayed instead of 0 when there are no matched you need to change the alternative value to NULL.  If only NULL values are passed to the aggregate function then NULL will be returned.

The one caveat is that using NULL instead of 0 in the SUM will produce the warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.  Otherwise everything is fine.

**EDIT**

That NULL Warning was bothering me.  An alternative that will produce the same results would be to transform the SOURCE column so that the values 'av', 'ax', 'nl' are turned into 'av+ax+nl' and then use pivot to get the sums by the source values of 'av+ax+nl'.

```
SELECT pvt.ID, pvt.[YEAR], pvt.[AV+AX+NL], pvt.OV
FROM (
    SELECT ID, [YEAR], [VALUE]
        , CASE WHEN SOURCE IN ('AV', 'AX', 'NL') THEN 'AV+AX+NL' ELSE SOURCE END SOURCE2
    FROM src
) src2
PIVOT (
    SUM([VALUE])
    FOR SOURCE2 IN ([AV+AX+NL], [OV])
) pvt
ORDER BY ID, [YEAR]
```

Comment: Why the down vote?  It's the exact results the O.P. wanted?

Comment: I'm not sure (it wasn't me who down voted). I think this work if I replace the zeroes with NULL

Comment: @rw2, I changed the zeros to null.  This does issue the Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation, but the query results work.

Answer (score 1):

One option is `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), ID + YEAR ~ SOURCE %in% c("AV", "AX", "NL"),
                value.var = "VALUE", sum)
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked well, and seemed to be a lot quicker than dplyr methods with my dataset

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this on Sql server, this is one

```
WITH C AS(
    SELECT ID
          ,YEAR
          ,SUM(VALUE) AS [AVAXNL]
    FROM TABLE_1
    WHERE SOURCE IN('AV','AX','NL')
    GROUP BY ID,YEAR

),D AS(
    SELECT ID
          ,YEAR
          ,SUM(VALUE) AS [OV]
        FROM TABLE_1
    WHERE SOURCE IN('AV','AX','NL')
    GROUP BY ID,YEAR
)
SELECT  ISNULL(C.ID,D.ID) AS ID
       ,ISNULL(C.YEAR,D.YEAR) AS YEAR
       ,C.AVAXNL
       ,D.OV
FROM C
FULL JOIN D ON (C.ID = D.ID AND C.YEAR = D.YEAR)
```

Also you can pivot your table and add each row.